# Update sObjects in .sfdx/typings

Tags: sobject, lightning-web-components, vs-code

I have a VSCode SFDX Project that we use to develop LWCs, and we recently changed some object names in the Org and now I can't upload anything to our Org.

I found that there is a command to `refresh sobjects`, so I ran that, but it only updated the sobjects in `.sfdx/tools`, but not `.sfdx/typings`.

How can I get all of the references to update so that I can actually upload into my org? Can you just delete the .sfdx folder and re-authorize an organization.

Comment: See the answer provided [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257036/how-to-refresh-or-regenerate-files-in-sfdx-typings).

Answer (score 0):

See the answer provided [here](http://See%20the%20answer%20provided%20[here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257036/how-to-refresh-or-regenerate-files-in-sfdx-typings).). I recently had the same question. I'm connected to a regular non-sourced sandbox org and have not yet seen this command work; however, it may work more reliably for sourced scratch orgs.